# Making google sheets random numbers or choices not update after a certain date or condition

Tags: random, google-sheets

I'm using `RANDBETWEEN` to choose a random item from a list in Google Sheets.

After a certain condition is true, such as after DATEDIFF is <= 0, I want the random choice that was made to be locked in and not change on refresh.

But I want other values, for future dates, to change (in case the list of choices changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I came up with is to copy and paste_special->values to replace the formula with the specific values up to the point in time that I care about.

Otherwise as @pnuts mentioned in comments, this would require a script.